# Using HTML5 Boilerplate

Tags: html, web, html5boilerplate

I have searched for guides on how to use Boilerplate, and have found nothing to really help me out, so I apologize if this has been asked before. I was just wondering how I use Boilerplate? I am a WebDev newbie and I'm not even sure what it is honestly. Is it like Notepad++? I.E. something I can write HTML in? Or...?

Comment: It's merely a bunch of files that are meant to help you develop a website. https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/v4.0.3/doc/usage.md

Comment: I guess I understand... I just don't really know how to implement it into a website (and the instructions / usage don't really explain it). All I know of HTML writing is that I write out the code/text in something like Notepad++ and it reads out as a website... I have no idea how to implement any of the files in Boilerplate.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest starting with boilerplate, I recommend achieving a firm grasp of the basics. This site may help: http://www.htmldog.com/guides/htmlbeginner/ Focus on basic HTML and CSS, I wouldn't even touch javascript for at least a couple months.

Comment: Anyone aware of boilerplate text manager plugin for Notepad++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A boilerplate is a bunch of files (HTML, CSS, JS libraries, configuration files, images, etc.) preconfigured to set a basic skeleton from which begin to customize and develop your own application (standalone or web).

Examples are [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) and [jQuery Boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/)

Usually these boilerplates have to be downloaded and unzipped into your development directory and customized.

Some projects ([Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) for example) aims to automate the whole process giving you a development structure ready to be customized.

Customization can be done with your usual tools (Notepad, TextMate, Sublime Text, Emacs, Dreamweaver, etc.).

However, it requires a good knowledge of many aspects of development to reach a good customization level (since you'll have to tweak many things in your starting skeleton), so if you're a newbie, I suggest to start with something easier and gradually approach to it.

Comment: thanks for mentioning Yeoman. I didn't know it, i was looking for something like this.

Comment: You're welcome @Fabio. Yeoman is one of the most active projects actually, but if search on GitHub you may find other projects similiar to it for more specific targets (but always customizable in some sort) such as Grunt, Bower, or Brunch.

Comment: thanks a lot..i'll take a look at them and other alternatives..